# Javascript 2D Array Contains always false (using PUSH)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently doing some tasks in Javascript.
I created a 2D Array at the beginning, completely empty:

```
  let stonearray =[[]];
```

Now whenever the user clicks on a certain position, i save the values and want to push them into the array so that the values are saved there:

```
var posx2 = Math.floor(x/colSize)*colSize+colSize/2;
var posy2 = Math.floor(y/rowSize)*rowSize+rowSize/2;
var pusharr = [[posx2, posy2]];
stonearray.push([pusharr]);
```

Now i want to know if the array pair (value of pusharray) is already stored in the stonearray - which it should be by now. But whenever i try to check if "stonearray" already contains the "pusharr" it always says false.
I tried these versions to check:

```
//first attempt:
var contains = stonearray.includes([pusharr]);

//second attempt:
 function checkContain(stonearray,pusharr) {

    let a;

    alert(pusharr);

    for (a = 0; a < stonearray.length; a++) {
        if (stonearray[a] === pusharr) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It is always returning false. But why? I am pretty new to Javascript. Please don't be to harsh on me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` and `.includes` does not do deep equality checks. You could do something like this though:

```js
const stonearr = [[1,2], [55, 22]];

function check2dArr(pushArr, arr) {
  return arr.some(a => {
    return pushArr[0] === a[0] && pushArr[1] === a[1];
  })
}

console.log(check2dArr([1, 2], stonearr));
console.log(check2dArr([55, 21], stonearr));
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is working perfectly fine. I didn't know those checks do not do deep equality checks, you never stop learning. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: If you do want a fast way to do deep equality checks you might checkout Lodash and use the isEqual function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isEqual

Answer (score 1):

First, you're pushing an array of array: `stonearray.push([pusharr])`, probably you need to push as follow: `stonearray.push(pusharr);`

```js
let x = 1, y = 2, colSize = 1, rowSize = 2;

let stonearray = [];

var posx2 = Math.floor(x / colSize) * colSize + colSize / 2;
var posy2 = Math.floor(y / rowSize) * rowSize + rowSize / 2;
var pusharr = [
  [posx2, posy2]
];

stonearray.push(pusharr);
function checkContain(stonearray, pusharr) {
  let a;
  for (a = 0; a < stonearray.length; a++) {
    if (stonearray[a] === pusharr) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(checkContain(stonearray, pusharr));
```

Now, the code snippet above works because **you're comparing the same value in memory**.  To guarantee a correct comparison, you need to compare the values within the array:

```js
let x = 1, y = 2, colSize = 1, rowSize = 2;

let stonearray = [];

var posx2 = Math.floor(x / colSize) * colSize + colSize / 2;
var posy2 = Math.floor(y / rowSize) * rowSize + rowSize / 2;
var pusharr = [
  [posx2, posy2]
];

stonearray.push(pusharr);
function checkContain(stonearray, pusharr) {
  for (let a = 0; a < stonearray.length; a++) {
    if (stonearray[a][0][0] === pusharr[0][0] && stonearray[a][0][1] === pusharr[0][1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(checkContain(stonearray, [[posx2, posy2]]));
```

Using the function `some` which compare the elements until a condition is `true`.

```js
let x = 1, y = 2, colSize = 1, rowSize = 2;

let stonearray = [];

var posx2 = Math.floor(x / colSize) * colSize + colSize / 2;
var posy2 = Math.floor(y / rowSize) * rowSize + rowSize / 2;
var pusharr = [
  [posx2, posy2]
];

stonearray.push(pusharr);
function checkContain(stonearray, pusharr) {
  return stonearray.some(array => array[0][0] === pusharr[0][0] && array[0][1] === pusharr[0][1])
}

console.log(checkContain(stonearray, [[posx2, posy2]]));
```